# View cache of ASP.NET process

Tags: asp.net

I want to view the cache keys and sizes of a running ASP.NET process. Is there any tools available to do this? Or any pointers on how to build a tool?

Answer (score 0):

We have written a webservice methods which are only for internal use to view and refresh cache. It can delete a specific cache key as well. We have hosted it along with the mail website. You can come up with this app by using asp.net caching api's.

Also you can go through [Monitor your ASP.NET Cache API Behaviour](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/07/20/monitor-your-asp-net-cache-api-behaviour.aspx)

Comment: I am looking at a tool similar to XAML Spy or Snoop for WPF applications. How is that - WPF applications can be snooped but not ASP.NET?